# Invocation of Polski Package Sometimes Produces Strange Hyphenation

Tags: enumitem, typography, hyphenation, quotation, polish

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor}

\usepackage[T1]{polski}

\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}  %This line must be commented out when using Xelatex to compile the Index

\usepackage[margin=.5in,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=6in]{geometry}
\textheight=4.95in \textwidth 3.00in

\newcommand{\longemdash}{{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont---}}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin} % Sets cabin as the main font.


\usepackage{xparse} % NEEDED TO USE \NewDocumentCommand instead of \newcommand.
\definecolor{granite}{RGB}{103,103,103}

\newcommand{\fancyquote}[2]{%
  \par{#1}\\[2pt]\hspace*{\fill}\longemdash{\fontfamily{qtm}\selectfont\textit{\textbf{#2}}}%
}

\newcommand{\funnyquote}[2]{%
  \par{#1}\\[-10.5pt]\hspace*{\fill}\longemdash{\fontfamily{qtm}\selectfont\textit{\textbf{#2}}}%
}

\newlist{advice}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[advice]{
  label=\formatadvicenumber{\textbf{\color{granite}\arabic*}},
  ref=\arabic*,
  leftmargin=1.25em,
  labelsep=.55em, 
  itemsep=1em, 
  wide=0pt, % Prevents numbers from entering the left-hand margin.
  resume,
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\formatadvicenumber}{m}{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr1.35\ht\strutbox-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\LARGE #1}%
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{advice}
\item \funnyquote{The more I think about language, the more it amazes me that people ever understand each other at all.}{Kurt G{\"{o}}del}
\end{advice}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

However, when I comment out `\usepackage[T1]{polski}`, I get

[image]

QUESTION: Can anyone suggest what may be causing the conflict in my code by invoking the `Polski` package---which I have used occasionally for correctly typesetting certain Polish names---and the incorrect hyphenation?

Thank you.

Comment: Do consider replacing `\usepackage[T1]{polski}` with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[polish]{babel}`. With this change, the word "more" will no longer get hyphenated.

Comment: @MIco Many thanks. Works nicely.

Comment: why do you want to hyphenate English using patterns designed for Polish ????

Comment: unrelated but `\usepackage{xparse} % NEEDED TO USE \NewDocumentCommand instead of \newcommand.` is false unless you have an old latex

Comment: @Mico that fixes righthyphenmin, but still is hyphenating English as Polish

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - You're right. If the document is mainly in English, one should run `\usepackage[polish,english]{babel}` along with, say, `\foreignlanguage{polish}{Piłsudski}` or `\foreignlanguage{polish}{Władysław Wróblewski}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to typeset a few (or even a lot) of Polish names, but the text is in English (or any other language), you should *not* load `polski`, which is for document in Polish (and is obsolete, in my opinion).

What you need is `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and, possibly `babel-polish` (if you prefer that such names can be hyphenated. Note that just removing `\usepackage[T1]{polski}` is not sufficient to solve your problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish,english]{babel}

\newcommand{\polishname}[1]{\foreignlanguage{polish}{#1}}
\providehyphenmins{polish}{22} % <-- what polski.sty does

\begin{document}

\polishname{Wojciech Szczęsny} is a goalkeeper; \polishname{Lech Wałęsa}
is a politician; \polishname{Karol Woityła} was a pope.

\bigskip

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}%
  \polishname{Wojciech Szczęsny} is a goalkeeper; \polishname{Lech Wałęsa}
  is a politician; \polishname{Karol Woityła} was a pope.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if you really need inserts in a foreign language yes, but I wouldn't normally do that just for names. Names in a bibliography are often not marked by language . As for T1/OT1 that (for english) is a separate issue, and hopefully the OP knows about that by now

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you inferred---I only need Polish occasionally.

Answer (score 4):

```
\usepackage[T1]{polski}
```

sets up *the entire document* for Polish so for example `\chapter{abc}` will no longer produce **Chapter 1 abc** but:

[image]

It also sets `\righthyphenmin` to 2 rather than 3 which is why you get `mo-re`, but as it is hyphenating English words using hyphenation patterns for Polish, all hyphenation will be wrong.

Simply delete

```
\usepackage[T1]{polski}
```

You do not need any special package "for correctly typesetting certain Polish names"